# Laravel 5.2 execute multiple db transactions then commit or rollback if failed

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel, working on 5.22. I am trying to save two records into two tables but only commit the changes if there is success on both fronts, else I want it to fail and rollback.

My Controller code for the save is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $all = $request->all();

    // we need to fill in who is the creator of this new user,
    $all['creator_user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

    // Commit both updates or fail and rollback
    DB::transaction(function ($all) {
        $client = Client::create($all);
        $orgClient['organisation_id'] = $client->organisation_id;
        $orgClient['client_id'] = $client->client_id;
        OrganisationClient::create($orgClient);
    });

    return redirect()
        ->route('client.index')
        ->withMessage([
            'type' => 'success',
            'value' => 'Client <strong>' . $all->client_name . '</strong> successfully created.']);

}
```

This fails with the error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/simply-invoice/app/Http/Controllers/ClientController.php on line 80
```

My problem seems to be passing `$all` to the closure. If I remove `$all` from the closure parameter, then I get `undefined variable all`. How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `$all` as the callback parameter instead of `use`ing it. The `transaction` callback is receiving an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Connection` as a parameter at the moment.

In order to get the actual variable you want you have to change your callback to this:

```php
// ....
DB::transaction(function () use($all) {
// ...
```